# ASP.NET Page directive: inherit codebehind from alternate assembly?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to set the Inherits attribute of an ASPX Page directive to a class in an arbitrary assembly?

I need to modify an ASP.NET (1.1) application for which the source code was lost. In a new assembly (foo2.dll) I've created a replacement code-behind class that derives from the original class in the site's code-behind assembly (foo.dll). It seems easy enough to set the Inherits attribute of the Page directive to the new class name, but when I do that the web server gives me `Could not load type 'Foo2.checkout2'`. I am referencing the new assembly in the `<assemblies>` section of Web.config.

I don't see anything in the documentation to indicate that this scenario is unsupported, but I'm not certain that it is, either.

Original

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Foo.checkout" language="c#" Codebehind="checkout.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
```

New

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Foo2.checkout2" CodeFile="checkout2.aspx.cs" CodeFileBaseClass="Foo.checkout" language="c#" Codebehind="checkout.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping the dll into the bin directory of the site?

Comment: Yes, Foo2.dll is in the site's bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. You have to add a reference like this 
[image]

It did not change the web.config but I had the reference in .csproj `<ItemGroup />` section like this

```
<Reference Include="WebApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\WebApplication2\bin\WebApplication2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: But .csproj would only be read by Visual Studio, not .NET/IIS. Is this reference used during compilation? Since I don't have source code for the original app, I'm not opening it in VS or recompiling it.